# VimScript: Is it possible to reduce a list into a dictionary like in JS?

Tags: vimscript

I've tried this but it didn't work

```
function! Reduce(array, oper, accumInit) abort
  let l:accum = a:accumInit
  for l:item in a:array
    let l:accum = a:oper(l:accum, l:item)
  endfor

  return l:accum
endfunction

function! FooBar() abort
  let g:foobar = Reduce(['pit', 'joh', 'dik'], {ac, el -> extend(ac, {[el]:len(el)})}, {})
endfunction
```

```
Error detected while processing function FooBar[1]..Reduce[3]..<lambda>3:
line    1:
E730: using List as a String
E116: Invalid arguments for function extend
```

Comment: Vim supports `reduce()` since [8.2.0878](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.0878). Vim9 supports `[key-expr]: value` since [8.2.2015](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.2015).

Comment: neovim and lua seem to be a future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the newest Vim version (not in Neovim yet) `reduce()` is a builtin.
2. Dictionary in VimScript can only have String keys (cf. AWK). For this reason, `[key]: value` notation is not even supported.
3. Obviously, if all items are strings anyway then you can have `{el: len(el)}`. Otherwise `{string(el): len(el)}` might also work for you. But, chances are, you need to re-think your problem completely.

Answer (score 4):

As Matt said, it should be `{e: len(e)}`.

Also, for efficiency with vimscript language, you should prefer `map()`, but this will introduce a new parameter in the `oper` function

```
call map(copy(a:array), {_, e -> extend(a:accumInit, {e: len(e)})})
return a:accumInit
```

It could be encapsulated in your `namespace#reduce()` function though:

```
call map(copy(a:array), {_, e -> extend(a:oper(a:accumInit, e))})
```